# Requirement of From where TryFrom is only required

Tags: rust, error-handling

I have a generic method over `S` that should take any argument that implements `TryInto<SomeType>` where `<S as TryInto>::Error` should implement `Into<SomeErrorType>` (`SomeErrorType` is associated with `SomeType` so I want to return `SomeErrorType` from the function that is associated with `SomeType` on failure). However the compiler is complaining that it also needs `From<S>` for `SomeType`.

Here is my code for the trait:

```rust
pub trait MathpixEndpoint {
    //[...]
    fn new<S>(options: Option<Self::Options>, src: S) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>
    where
        S: TryInto<Self::Src>,
        Self::Error: From<<S as TryInto<Self::Src>>::Error>;
    //[...]
}
```

And my implementation:

```rust
impl MathpixEndpoint for Text {
    //[...]
    fn new<S>(options: Option<Self::Options>, src: S) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>
    where
        S: TryInto<ImageSrc>,
        TextError: From<<S as TryInto<Self::Src>>::Error>,
    {
        let text_options = if let Some(options) = options {
            options
        } else {
            Self::Options::default()
        };
        let text_src: Self::Src = src.try_into()?;
        Ok(Self {
            src: text_src,
            options: text_options,
        })
    }
    //[...]
}
```

The compiler is complaining:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `ImageSrc: From<S>` is not satisfied
  --> src/endpoint/text/mod.rs:33:5
   |
33 | /     fn new<S>(options: Option<Self::Options>, src: S) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>
34 | |     where
35 | |         S: TryInto<ImageSrc>,
36 | |         TextError: From<<S as TryInto<Self::Src>>::Error>,
...  |
47 | |         })
48 | |     }
   | |_____^ the trait `From<S>` is not implemented for `ImageSrc`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Into<ImageSrc>` for `S`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `TryFrom<S>` for `ImageSrc`
help: consider introducing a `where` bound, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
   |
27 | impl MathpixEndpoint for Text where ImageSrc: From<S> {
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I do not know what is going on... Why would the compiler want a `From` implementation if I only declared `TryFrom` as a requirement.

The error type is implemented with `thiserror`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why the compiler assumes the blanket implementations that fall back to `From`. A potential fix is to declare the `Error` type as a generic argument `E`. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a38cf1af736849b74e1899e97e0f6fa):

```
use std::convert::TryInto;

pub trait MathpixEndpoint {
    type Src;
    type Error;
    type Options;

    fn new<S, E>(options: Option<Self::Options>, src: S) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>
    where
        S: TryInto<Self::Src, Error = E>,
        Self::Error: From<E>,
        Self: Sized;
}

struct ImageSrc;
struct Text;
struct TextError;

impl MathpixEndpoint for Text {
    type Src = ImageSrc;
    type Error = TextError;
    type Options = ();
    
    fn new<S, E>(options: Option<Self::Options>, src: S) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>
    where
        S: TryInto<ImageSrc, Error = E>,
        TextError: From<E>,
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there is no way of the compiler to know which error type will be returned through `TryFrom` so it needs to be generic?